# The right way to split a string into zero or more words

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string with zero or more whitespace-separated words, that needs to be split into an array of words. This is what I did. But the post-processing step, where I handle the case that the input string contained no words, suggests to me that I should have used some other way than String.split(). Should I?

```
String[] split_arguments(String arguments) {
    String[] result = arguments.split("[\t ]+");
    if (result.length == 1 && result[0].equals("")) {
        result = new String[0];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply trim the leading and trailing whitespace and check for that case prior to splitting.  Also, you might simply use the predefined whitespace character class.

```
String[] split_arguments(String arguments) {
    if(arguments == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String trimmedArguments = arguments.trim();
    if(trimmedArguments.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return trimmedArguments.split("\\s+");
}
```

Comment: Even better with a few minor tweaks.  But don't get me wrong, using StringUtils here would be quite appropriate.  I just wanted to give an answer without any other dependencies.

Comment: Good catch.  I always forget about that.

Comment: Also it should be noted that reassigning an input parameter here is not really a best practice.  Getting into that habit can lead to some funky bugs down the road.

Comment: It should also be noted, that this technique really only separates the character set into whitespace characters and word characters.  Meaning that alphanumeric and other symbols will all be treated as word characters.

Comment: Actually, trim() is already done, but yes, this works. I had hoped to find a splitter that was more suited for my needs "out of the box", but I guess that a check before splitting is better both aesthetically and performance-wise than my post-processing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) from Apache Commons. You can then either use one of the split methods they provide or before make a check that the string is not empty using the `isNotEmpty()` or `isNotBlank()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `StringUtils.IsBlank` from apache commons to check the string before splitting. Either way, you have to do a check, but doing a check before splitting might be more logical.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the StrTokenizer from Commons Lang. It's as simple as:

```
return StrTokenizer(arguments).getTokentArray();
```

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrTokenizer.html